# How to "join" two tables without PRIMARY KEYs

Tags: query

I have two tables in which there are no primary nor foreign keys.

- Table 1 (Persons):
  name, region, department
- Table 2 (Access):
  name, access_level

How can I answer the following question:

> How many people in each department have data access?

Comment: Once you have your answer, it probably goes without saying, but amend your table definitions to give yourself a decent primary key column (int identity column for example).

Answer (score 3):

If we're to assume that these tables are actually used to determine who has access, then the query from blobbles' answer is the answer, even if there are multiple people with the same name in `Persons`.

If there are 4 "John Smith"s in `Persons`, and `Access` indicates "John Smith" has data access, then every "John Smith" would have data access.

If this is merely a record of access granted (rather than what defines the access granted), and `Persons`.`name` is not unique, then you can't know for certain. Perhaps two "John Smith"s have been granted access, perhaps only 1, perhaps none. The record is incomplete, because we don't know how access ties back to different `Persons` with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

First check how unique the persons name is with something like:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*)
FROM Persons
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If this returns rows, you may have to exclude these people from the next step. If it doesn't return rows, join on "name" as it is unique in the Persons table:

```
SELECT p.department, COUNT(*)
FROM Persons p
INNER JOIN Access a ON p.name = a.name
GROUP BY p.department
```